# Determining if the number is odd or even

Tags: python

I am putting this in,

---

```
def check(digit):
     if digit % 2 == 0:
         print("Even number")

check()
```

---

and in return i am getting an error which says,

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
 check()
 TypeError: check() missing 1 required positional argument: 'digit'
```

Can anyone help me figure what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Pass the required parameter to your function like: `check(100)`

Comment: What's with these downvotes, guys?

Comment: For the record, your function would be more useful if named appropriately (`def is_odd(digit)` would be good) and if it returns its result instead of printing it. `def is_odd(digit): return digit%2` would work fine, because then you can test `if is_odd(7): #do something`

Comment: @Calpratt downvotes are because this is an elementary question on how to pass parameters to a function, which is not well-suited to SO. OP would be better served consulting a Python tutorial.

Comment: @AdamSmith I like SO fine for my simple Python problems. Where's the harm in recording this with a good answer for another newbie to find?

Comment: @iwein If the error was in any way unclear, I'd agree. But the error is quite specific and clear about what the problem is: there is a parameter missing.

Comment: @iwein No harm at all, as you'll see from not one but three good answers to OP's question. That said, this is not a GOOD question so there's little reason to be awarding it upvotes. Indeed, the lack of research (literally a google search for "missing required positional argument") combined with the trivial nature of the error leads me to vote to close due to typographical error or non-repro.

Comment: @towr But to someone who doesn't know what that means.. or who doesn't know what to google when an exception spits back a jumble of red gibberish at them- it is an appropriate question. This question is specific to his problem, gives all required information for us to help him, and can help someone else down the road.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is wrong. Try this:

```
def check(digit):
     if digit % 2:
         print("Odd number")
     else:
         print("Even number")
```

You need to supply the number that you want to check!

```
check(5)
Odd number
check(2)
Even number
```

Answer (score 6):

You are not calling your function `check` with any arguments. You also have to indent your `if` statement.

```
def check(digit):
     if digit % 2 == 0:
         print("Even number")
     else:
         print("Odd number")

check(3) # Prints "Odd number"
check(4) # Prints "Even number"
```

Comment: WOW! i get it, i see my mistake, I am sorry for this very dumb basic question, i am currently new with the program. Thanks!!

Comment: Palermox: Not knowing something is **not** the same thing as dumb. Just keep learning ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a number to your function, like `check(2)`.  Otherwise how can it know what number to check?